# Why is it giving me this error when trying to work with APIs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to working with react and APIs and I keep getting an error when trying to use an API, why is it? (I just learned how to use APIs in js and was trying to do the same in React):

> *Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field accepts is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

The code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function JokesCard() {
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState("");

  async function getDadJoke() {
    try {
      const config = { headers: { Accepts: "application/json" } };
      const res = axios.get("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/", config);
      setJoke(res.data.joke);
    } catch (e) {
      setJoke("No jokes available!");
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="text-center mt-10">
      <div className="mx-auto text-left flex flex-col items-center w-4/12 border-2 rounded-lg p-5">
        <p>{joke}</p>
        <button onClick={getDadJoke} className="self-end">
          Next joke ➡️
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: That error means that the API endpoint you're calling does not include CORS headers in the response. This means that the API owner is expressly denying access to their content from remote requests made from front-end JS. If you want to get the content you would need to make the request from the server-side instead, or find a different API.

Comment: Oh ok! So the problem is with the API provider and not the code?

Comment: Yes, although it's more to do with permissions than a 'problem'. The small code example in your question seems fine.

Comment: The problem is related to CORS. Lookup "http cors" in your favorite search engine. Ultimately it's between you and the API provider.